# add localStorage on click event of button

Tags: javascript, local-storage

This is an expand button click event and I want users to be able to save their settings

How to add `localStorage` to save it

```
$(".expand").click(function() {
    $(".megavid").toggleClass("xp");
    $(".pd-expand").toggleClass("sxp");
});

$('.expand').click(function() {
    if ($('.expand').hasClass('slamdown')) {
      $('.expand').removeClass('slamdown');
      jQuery(".mvelement").prependTo(jQuery(".megavid"));
    } else {
      $('.expand').addClass('slamdown');
      jQuery(".mvelement").appendTo(jQuery(".pd-expand"));
    }
});
```